# Selenium: NoSuchElementException even after using explicit Wait

Tags: python, selenium

I am locating an element on http://ntry.com/#/stats/ladder/round.php,
but I keep failing locating it, after trying several ways, including
ind_element_by_css_selector, ind_element_by_xpath... and so on.

Even though I used WebDriverWait, I keep failing. What would be the Problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://ntry.com/#/stats/ladder/round.php")

try:
   element = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="analysis-table"]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/span[1]/strong'))

   #or element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#analysis-table>div.bar_graph>div:nth-child(1)>p.left.on>span.per>strong"))
   )
except:
   print "HIJUDE"

driver.quit()
```

I used Implicit wait, but that also makes same error.
Not using Wait makes NoSuchElementException too.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":'//div[@id="analysis-table"]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/span[1]/strong'}
```

Is the website related with being unable to find the Element? or using method other than Xpath or css_selector would do? I am pretty confused why this happened.

-------------Edit--------------
I found out that there is iframe at the upper xpath level of div[@id="analysis-table"]. I guess that's the reason. Should I always use driver.switch_to_frame()
in this case? Btw, is driver.switch_to_window() different from frame()?

Comment: What is .on on p.left.on? I don't see an "on" class...

Comment: I found that the class names become different time to time, because this site is dynamic webpage. but using Xpath above seem to be always valid.

Comment: Yes, if you have an `iframe` element you will need to switch to the frame and then it should be able to find the element.

Comment: Yes, switing to iframe using driver.switch_to_frame() worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in `p.left.on` in the path. One element has single class `left` and the other one classes `right` and `on`. It should be

```
"#analysis-table>div.bar_graph>div:nth-child(1)>p.left>span.per>strong"
```

Or

```
"#analysis-table>div.bar_graph>div:nth-child(1)>p.right.on>span.per>strong"
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I guess the reason is because of <iframe> above div level. I will tell using switch_to_frame() fixes or not.